# How do I find the number of elements taking up memory for an expanded view of a pytorch tensor?

Tags: python, memory, pytorch

[`Tensor.expand()`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.Tensor.expand.html#torch.Tensor.expand) returns a new view of an underlying tensor, but doesn't actually allocate more memory for the expanded view.

If I have a tensor that is the result of calling `expand()` (some unknown number of times), how can I tell how many cells are actually allocated in memory for the tensor (in my actual use-case, I really just care about knowing whether or not that number is 1)?

Is there something like what I'm calling `elements_in_memory` as used in the following?:

```py
import torch

t = torch.tensor(4.0)
t2 = t.expand(3, 4)
t3 = t2.unsqueeze(0).expand(5, 3, 4)

# I'm looking for something like this (which doesn't work) 
assert t.elements_in_memory == 1
assert t2.elements_in_memory == 1
assert t3.elements_in_memory == 1
```

Some things I've tried:

- [`t.data_ptr`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.Tensor.data_ptr.html#torch.Tensor.data_ptr) refers to the first element of the underlying tensor in memory, so `t.data_ptr == t2.data_ptr`, but that doesn't tell me how many elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like `t.storage().size()` is what I'm after.

From the [`torch.Tensor` documentation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensors.html):

> Each tensor has an associated [torch.Storage](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/storage.html), which holds its data. The tensor class also provides multi-dimensional, strided view of a storage and defines numeric operations on it.

[`Tensor.storage()`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.Tensor.storage.html#torch.Tensor.storage) returns a reference to the storage used for the tensor:

```py
import torch

t = torch.tensor(4.0)
t2 = t.expand(3, 4)
t3 = t2.unsqueeze(0).expand(5, 3, 4)

assert t.storage().size() == 1
assert t2.storage().size() == 1
assert t3.storage().size() == 1

t4 = torch.ones(3, 4)
t5 = t4.unsqueeze(0).expand(5, 3, 4)

assert t4.storage().size() == 12
assert t5.storage().size() == 12
```

Note that the underlying storage might also include *more* elements than are exposed by some particular view (this wasn't relevant to my use-case).  For example `torch.ones(10)[3:6].storage().size() == 10`.